# How to add a new entry to an array after a certain property changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add a new entry to an array after a certain property, in my case " place", changes. However, I have big problems to find a suitable approach, because the operation depends on the next object in the array.

```
const initalData = [
  { storyID: 1, place: 12, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 5, place: 12, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 99, place: 45, type: "Story" }, 
  { storyID: 8, place: 31, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 16, place: 31, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 20, place: 45, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 22, place: 45, type: "Story" },
];
```

```
const targetData = [
  { placeID: 12, type: "Place" }, // new added entry based on the next  "place"
  { storyID: 1, place: 12, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 5, place: 12, type: "Story" },
  { placeID: 45, type: "Place" }, // // new added entry based on the next  "place"
  { storyID: 99, place: 45, type: "Story" },
  { placeID: 31, type: "Place" }, // new added entry based on the next  "place"
  { storyID: 8, place: 31, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 16, place: 31, type: "Story" },
  { placeID: 45, type: "Place" },// new added entry based on the next  "place"
  { storyID: 20, place: 45, type: "Story" },
  { storyID: 22, place: 45, type: "Story" },
];
```

Currently I have looked at `groupBy("place")` as a possible approach, but the ultimate array structure here is not what I need.

Comment: Can you add some details in order to get better understanding of the problem

Comment: From the UI perspective, imagine something like a playlist. Before the story changes, the place (currently only included in the story object) should be displayed. The UI component that renders the list takes only a flatlist and can differentiate the render item based on the "type" and "index".

Comment: Do you mean like a treeview??

Comment: The input data needs to be flat. The final ui will contain sections and a tree like structure.

Comment: Have two arrays - one is your original/input array (`initialData`) & another an empty array. Add place-id to the empty array as first element (at index-0) based on `initialData`'s first element. Then, iterate from 1 to length of `initialData` and when previous-index & current-index `place` is not same, simply add an element to the output array. Fairly simple logic. Please let me know if this helps - or if an answer is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the implementation

```js
const initalData = [
    { storyID: 1, place: 12, type: "Story" },
    { storyID: 5, place: 12, type: "Story" },
    { storyID: 99, place: 45, type: "Story" },
    { storyID: 8, place: 31, type: "Story" },
    { storyID: 16, place: 31, type: "Story" },
    { storyID: 20, place: 45, type: "Story" },
    { storyID: 22, place: 45, type: "Story" },
];

let oldPlace = null;
let resultData = [];

for (let row of initalData) {
    if (row.place != oldPlace) {
        resultData.push({ placeID: row.place, type: "Place" });
        oldPlace = row.place;
    }
    resultData.push(row);
}

console.log (resultData);
```

[image]